# How well will Pantone neon inks translate on to a can?

Tags: color, print-design, pantone, packaging

Specifically on aluminum cans? I'm wanting to design a neon pink can (PMS 806C) but can't find any images or references to this being done before, and how good or bad neons will translate onto a can. I don't want them to look muddy or faded. I want them to be like, blinding. Has anyone ever used neon inks on cans before? I work with Crown and they say they don't have any samples to send me unfortunately. I just want to know if it'll look bad before I go designing the whole thing, only to get a pilot can and have it look like garbage.

If anyone's got pictures or advice I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: There is a big chance you need to print a white color base for the color to be bright.

Comment: Yes; there will be white on the can already, as a solid bottom layer to make the colors more opaque. White's required on cans anyway typically to knock the UPC out of so that it's scanable. I'm just wondering if anyone has done this before and how it came out.

Answer (score 3):

If you already have a white base on the can I see no aditional problem to reproduce the desired PMS color.

I had one project printed on metal, and once the metal is covered with the white the color responds pretty much like coated paper.

If the inks used are the correct type for the metal they should be ok.

There is a chance it will also have a varnish that will make the colors pop a bit more.

Comment: Rafael is right on. Plus, if you mess around with screening the white layer back a bit, you can get some really cool metallic effects in your artwork (I'd check with the printer on this first).

Comment: I am adding this as a coment. Not only playing with the screening but printing in some zones directly on the can. The look would be similar to some christmass spheres. Something like the (F) example here: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/77089/prototype-visualization-how-can-i-learn-to-render-glass-convincingly/77256#77256 you can test this simply smudgin some ink on the can with the finger.